# Using NSlog with cross platform style

Tags: ios, nslog

I am creating an iphone test using c++,and I want to use nslog( the only way to show debug information?) whenever I want to include nslog function my cpp has to change to mm right? is it the only way to do it? because I don't want to change back to cpp when I move to other platform.

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since NSLog only exists on Objective-C platforms, why not create your own `LogMessage()` method taking standard C++ arguments in a single .mm file that calls NSLog and call that from C++ files named as usual. That way you'll not need to rename every single file that needs to log to .mm

On other platforms, just include another implementation of `LogMessage()` since there's no NSLog to call there anyway.